# Spring multiple Datasource not reading some application properties

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, datasource

I'm struggling with something like for more than a week. The thing is I need 2 datasources because my application has its own database, but also need to retrieve information for another database.

First I resolved to communicate with the 2 databases, which I had problems at the beginning, but now sometimes when the app is trying to connect to one of the databases the one who uses jdbcTemplate closes the connections after maybe 1 hour or less and gets an exception and no longer can be establish a connection. I suppose that configuring some properties from the tomcat pooling will help to solve this issue but this ones are not been reading by the datasource. So here is my application properties and database configuration class to clarify all this stuff.

**Application Properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/firstDB
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=user1
spring.datasource.password=password1
spring.jpa.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor=org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

# --------------------
# CONFIGURACION SECOND
# --------------------

spring.sia.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.202:5432/secondDB
spring.sia.datasource.tomcat.remove-abandoned=true
spring.sia.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=20
spring.sia.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.sia.datasource.username=user2
spring.sia.datasource.password=password2
```

**DBConfig:**

```
@Configuration
public class DbConfig {

    @Bean(name="firstDb")
    @Primary
    public DataSourceProperties firstDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource firstDataSource() {
        return firstDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.sia.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties secondDataSourceProperties(){
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name="siaDb")
    public DataSource secondDataSource() {        
        return secondDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean(name="siaJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("siaDb") DataSource dataSource) {

        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);

        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

}
```

The problem is that **this** properties:

```
spring.sia.datasource.tomcat.remove-abandoned=true
spring.sia.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=20
```

Are not been reading for the second datasource, maybe I'm missing something with the configuration class.

Do I need to create a manual Datasource?? If so what's the point of having the **@ConfigurationProperties** annotation and the call to the datasourcebuilder??

I'll appreciate all your help because I need to figure out first if the tomcat pooling properties solve this issue or maybe is something different.

**This is the exception that occurs after trying to hit an endpoint of the application.**

```
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:342) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:366) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.getErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:212) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.setDataSource(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:134) [spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.<init>(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:97) [spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.getExceptionTranslator(JdbcAccessor.java:99) [spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649) [spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:684) [spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:716) [spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:726) [spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:776) [spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at com.swargos.api.repositories.ServicioSiaRepositoryImpl.getAllServiciosByUsuario(ServicioSiaRepositoryImpl.java:112) [classes!/:na]
    at com.swargos.api.repositories.ServicioSiaRepositoryImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f87228d2.invoke(<generated>) [classes!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) [spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) [spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) [spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at com.swargos.api.repositories.ServicioSiaRepositoryImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a929bedc.getAllServiciosByUsuario(<generated>) [classes!/:na]
    at com.swargos.api.services.ServicioSiaServiceImpl.findServiciosByUsuario(ServicioSiaServiceImpl.java:37) [classes!/:na]
    at com.swargos.api.controllers.ServicioSiaController.getServiciosCurrentUser(ServicioSiaController.java:54) [classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor98.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
```

Thanks

Comment: can u try providing tomcat connection properties for both the data sources and check ?

Comment: I already edit the exception that I get... but I wanna know if the tomcat properties solve this issue...

Comment: i pasted my output below in the answers section.. u might want to try.. i would say unless u try adding the connection properties and test you would not know if that would resolve the issue or not.

Comment: That's the reason of the question... I already try it, but the tomcat properties are not loaded... how do I know?? because I output the dataSource, and the values of this properties are not there.

Answer (score 0):

these errors can be very tricky to resolve. Can you post the stacktrace of the exception you get ?

As a start can u try providing tomcat connection properties for both the data sources and check.

I did create 2 datasources recently for a project and provided tomcat connection properties both datasources.

```
db1.database.maximumPoolSize=100
db1.database.connectionTimeout=30000
db1.database.validationTimeout=5000
db1.database.idleTimeout=60000
db1.database.leakDetectionThreshold=400000
db1.database.maxLifetime=600000
db1.database.minIdle=-1
db1.database.poolName=hikari-app
db1.database.isRegisterMbeans=true

db2.database.maximumPoolSize=100
db2.database.connectionTimeout=30000
db2.database.validationTimeout=5000
db2.database.idleTimeout=60000
db2.database.leakDetectionThreshold=400000
db2.database.maxLifetime=600000
db2.database.minIdle=-1
db2.database.poolName=hikari-app2
db2.database.isRegisterMbeans=true
```